# Scrape value from inside a list python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have an HTML document from which I scrape some data using

```
data=content.find_all("a", {"class": "result-title"})
```

Then data as below:

```
[ < a class = "result-title hover_feedback zred bold ln24 fontsize0 "
    data - result - type = "ResCard_Name"
    href = "https://www.zomato.com/bangalore/flechazo-marathahalli"
    title = "flechazo Restaurant, Marathahalli" > Flechazo <
    /a>]
```

Now I wanted extract from `data` is 
01. https://www.zomato.com/bangalore/flechazo-marathahalli
02. Flechazo

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I doubt that your data looks like this, with syntax errors all over the place.

Comment: Could we please have your **exact** output and input.  Your output is invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will help

```
links = content.find_all("a", {"class": "result-title"})    
for link in links:
    print(link.get('href', None))
    print(link.text)
```

**Output**

```
https://www.zomato.com/bangalore/flechazo-marathahalli
Flechazo
```